# Error generating referral link in php

Tags: php, helper

I would like to create a referral link but I had a problem I would like each link to be unique but I did not know how to do it and put a rand line something like this

```
  <br>
 <center>Реферальная ссылка: 
<input value="http://example .com/?ref=<?php
    if ($a > $b) {
       echo rand() . "\n";
    } elseif ($a == $b) {
        echo rand() . "\n";
    } else {
        echo rand(5, 15);
    }
    ?>" " onClick="select()" size="30" type="text"></center>
    <br />
```

What should I do to make the referral link unique to each user?

Comment: What is a and b? We need to see more code to figure out what's going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php has a function called uniqid documentation can be found [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php). The ID is unique as it..:

> Gets a prefixed unique identifier based on the current time in microseconds.

Read through the docs and see what you can come up with seems like a very interesting function, it has some examples that imagine you could fairly easily implement to achieve your goals, it does seem like it has some flaws but people have somewhat addressed them in the documentation also, good luck!